# Make only one widget float above the keyboard in Flutter

Tags: flutter, keyboard, widget, floating

I want to display a "Close keyboard" button above the keyboard when it is visible.

I know that the resizeToAvoidBottomInset can impact how the keyboard interact with the rest of the application, however it doesn't do exactly what I want.

I have a background image and others widgets (not shown in the sample below) which should not be resized and not moved when the keyboards is shown. This is an ok behavior when the `resizeToAvoidBottomInset` attribute is set to false.

However, I would like to add a button which *should* appear above the keyboard.

How can I do that? I only want one widget floating above the keyboard, not all the app.

Here is a sample code :

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var home = MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page');
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: home,
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: _getBody(),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _getBody() {
    return Stack(children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage("assets/sample.jpg"), fit: BoxFit.fitWidth)),
        // color: Color.fromARGB(50, 200, 50, 20),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[TextField()],
        ),
      ),
      Positioned(
        bottom: 0,
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
        child: Container(
          height: 50,
          child: Text("Aboveeeeee"),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.pink),
        ),
      ),
    ]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Your `Positioned` widget has a `bottom` of 0, replacing with an appropriate value should do the job.

`MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom` will give you the value of the height covered by the system UI(in this case the keyboard).

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var home = MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page');
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: home,
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: _getBody(),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _getBody() {
    return Stack(children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage("assets/sample.jpg"), fit: BoxFit.fitWidth)),
        // color: Color.fromARGB(50, 200, 50, 20),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[TextField()],
        ),
      ),
      Positioned(
        bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom,
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
        child: Container(
          height: 50,
          child: Text("Aboveeeeee"),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.pink),
        ),
      ),
    ]);
  }
}
```

[image: gif]

Comment: how can this works? does it naturally rebuild every after keyboard show up?

Comment: I know a lot of time has passed, but basically having MediaQuery.of(context) anywhere in your widget means it will rebuild when states of the phone change like rotation, keyboard showing up etc.

Answer (score 5):

### 2022 Update

A PR was merged that provides platform-synchronized animations for closing/opening the keyboard. See the [PR in effect here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19279#issuecomment-948769239).

### Detailed Answer

To achieve keyboard-visibility-based animated padding, here are a few modifications over @10101010's great answer:

If you want the `bottom` change when keyboard changes visibility to be animated *AND* you want extra padding under your floating child then:

### 1- Use [keyboard_visibility](https://pub.dev/packages/keyboard_visibility) flutter pub

To listen when keyboard is appearing/disappearing, like so:

```
  bool isKeyboardVisible = false;
  
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    KeyboardVisibilityNotification().addNewListener(
      onChange: (bool visible) {
        isKeyboardVisible = visible;
      },
    );
  }
```

Optionally you can write your own native plugins, but it's already there you can check the pub's git repo.

### 2- Consume visibility flag in your `AnimatedPostioned`:

For fine-tuned animated padding, like so:

```
Widget _getBody() {
    double bottomPadding = 0;
    if (isKeyboardVisible) {
      // when keyboard is shown, our floating widget is above the keyboard and its accessories by `16`
      bottomPadding = MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom + 16;
    } else {
      // when keyboard is hidden, we should have default spacing
      bottomPadding = 48; // MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.15;
    }

    return Stack(children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage("assets/sample.jpg"), fit: BoxFit.fitWidth)),
        // color: Color.fromARGB(50, 200, 50, 20),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[TextField()],
        ),
      ),
      AnimatedPositioned(
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
        bottom: bottomPadding,
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
        child: Container(
          height: 50,
          child: Text("Aboveeeeee"),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.pink),
        ),
      ),
    ]);
}
```

### 3- Keyboard-specific animation curve and duration for synchronized animation

For now this is still an [known ongoing issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19279#issuecomment-553742546)

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `bottomSheet` of a `Scaffold` widget.

Example:

```
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("New Game"),
      ),
      bottomSheet: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 18, vertical: 16),
          color: Colors.blue,
          child: const SizedBox(
            width: double.infinity,
            height: 20,
            child: Text("Above Keyboard"),
          ))
...
)
```

[image] [image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use bottomSheet parameter of the Scaffold, which keep a persistent bottom sheet. See below code.

```
class InputScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Close')),
      bottomSheet: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 18, vertical: 16),
          color: Colors.black,
          child: const SizedBox(width: double.infinity, height: 10)),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          const TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
              hintText: 'Enter your input here',
            ),
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            child: const Text('Submit'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**If Stack method Failed??

That Positioned  bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom!!
Then go through this method**

> Use bottomsheet and put your button widget there

> Wrap with SingleChildScrollView if you need scroll body part

> Sample code & attachments below

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: const SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
        children: [
          // your Widgets here
          //Textfield 1
          //Textfield 2
          //Textfield 3
        ],
      )),
      bottomSheet: SizedBox(
        height: 70,
        child: ButtonWidget(
          buttonName: "Continue",
          onpressed: () {
            //Button press code here
            context.pushRoute(const SignUpStepsPageRoute());
          },
        ),
      ));
}
```

> Output will be

[image: Image that keyboard open / close state]

Comment: Perfect approach!

Answer (score 0):

check this [package,](https://pub.dev/packages/keyboard_actions) it can show a dismiss button above the keyboard.

Comment: That package is interesting and in the same idea of what I want to do, however the solution mentioned by @10101010 is easier to implement in my case.